# Show that the radical of the ideal is equal $ \langle X,Y\rangle $

Tags: ideals, radicals

$\def\Rad{\operatorname{Rad}}$
Could you give me some hints how I can solve the followig exercise?

Show that the $\Rad(I)$ of the ideal $I=\langle X^5,Y^3\rangle $ of the ring $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ is $\Rad(I)=\langle X,Y\rangle $.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the radical of $\langle X^5, Y^3\rangle$ contains $X,Y$, and it does not contain $1$.

But now, $\langle X, Y\rangle$ is a maximal ideal contained in the radical of $I$, so it must be equal to it.

Comment: $$\Rad(I(=\{a \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y] | \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } a^n \in I\}$$

$$X^5 \in I \Rightarrow X \in \Rad(I)$$

$$Y^3 \in I \Rightarrow Y \in \Rad(I)$$

$$\Rightarrow \langle X, Y \rangle \subseteq \Rad(I)$$


Is it right? Or have I done something wrong?  


In order to show that $\langle X, Y \rangle \supseteq \Rad(I)$ do we have to do it like that?

Let $a \in \Rad(I) \Rightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^n \in I=\langle X^5, Y^3 \rangle $, that means that $ a^n=X^5k+Y^3\lambda , k, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

But... how could I continue?

Comment: @evinda equality follows since $\langle X,Y \rangle$ is maximal.

Comment: In my notes, there is the following:

$$\text{ If } M \text{ maximal } \Rightarrow M \text{ prime } \Rightarrow M=Rad(M) \ \ \ \ \ (*)$$

But in this case, we don't have to show that $Rad(I)=I$, we have to show that $Rad(\langle X^5, Y^3 \rangle )=\langle X, Y \rangle $.

Does the relation $(*)$ also stand in this case?

Comment: You can use maximality argument. Since $\langle X,Y \rangle \subseteq \sqrt{I} \neq R$...

Comment: Crostul Could you explain me further what I have to do? :/

Comment: Do you know the definition of maximal ideal? $M$ is maximal iff $M \subseteq J \neq R \Rightarrow M=J$.

Comment: Crostul So in this case we have that $M=\langle X,Y \rangle $ and $J=Rad(I)$ and $R$ is the ring $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$, right?